# Django - joining two many-to-one relationships

Tags: django, orm

I am stuck trying to write a Django ORM query to get the analogue of the following query:

```
vendors = Vendors.objects.select_related('legal_entities') #....and then I want to also get legal_entities_details
```

My model:

```
  class LegalEntitiesDetails(models.Model):
        legal_entities = models.ForeignKey(LegalEntities, models.CASCADE)
    class LegalEntities(models.Model):
        #...Some fields
    class Vendors(models.Model):
        legal_entities = models.ForeignKey(LegalEntities, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I can't figure out how to do it via select_related.  The problem as you see is that I can't write a simple chained selected_related because both vendors and legal_entities_details relate to legal_entities. Please bear with me with this question, I am a newbie to Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried prefetch related? From docs:

> select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason, select_related gets the related objects in the same database query. However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
>
> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each
>   relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to
>   prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done
>   using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one
>   relationships that are supported by select_related.
>   [more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

also when your relationship is not directly defined in the Class you are prefetching from, you can use classname_set to spawn reverse relationship

something like this should work:

```
Vendors.objects.select_related('legal_entities')
               .prefetch_related('legal_entities__legalentitiesdetails_set')
```

Comment: And how do I refer to legal_entities_details then ?

Comment: I try something like sp.legal_entities__legal_entities_details

Comment: I am not completely sure how is camelCase exploded. Either try prefetch_related('legal_entities__legalentitiesdetails_set') or prefetch_related('legal_entities__legal_entities_details_set'). Either way don't forget to append _set at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `select_related`, since that only works on forwards relations and the link between LegalEntities and LegalEntitiesDetails is a backwards relation. You'll need to use `prefetch_related`, which can follow backwards relations but uses two queries to do so.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. Could you please provide a short example of how to write the query. Just in order to know the best practice